# Wind velocity dependence of the temperature of a cylinder

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

I am currently looking for a way to model the temperature as a function of time $t$ and velocity $v$ (of the wind rushing past), of a metal cylinder that is being supplied with some heat $Q$ (a constant), with some radius $r$ and some length $l$.

How would I model this? I first considered using a thermodynamical approach, modelling the temperature gradient radially across the air $T(r)$, assuming the temperature of the cylinder would be uniform. But that only allows me to solve for the equilibrium temperature, and not a dynamic one.

Are there any resources that I can be linked to, that describe this phenomenon quantitatively? I am looking for a mathematical model that gives me $T(t,v)$, and possibly $x$, across the length of the cylinder.

Would I have to look into fluid mechanics? This sounds like a convection problem. Are there any specific topics or materials you'd recommend I study?

Also, if the cylinder were to be replaced with a coil (effectively now a hollow rod), how would things change?

Comment: Are you talking about forced flow normal to a cylinder?

Answer (score 0):

See Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Chapter 14, Section 14.4 Heat Transfer Coefficients for Forced Convection Around Submerged Objects, Flow Around a Cylinder

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer!